# Squid proxy not caching anything

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, cache

squid.conf:

```
http_access allow all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128 accel defaultsite=localhost no-vhost

cache_peer localhost parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=myAccel
cache_peer_access myAccel allow all

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /usr/local/var/cache/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /usr/local/var/cache/squid
```

Squid 3.2.9, installed on OSX via Homebrew

```
localhost: ~ $ squid -v
Squid Cache: Version 3.2.9
configure options:  '--disable-debug' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/squid/3.2.9' '--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' 'CC=cc' 'CXX=c++' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
```

Started squid with `squid -f squid.conf -d 2 -N`

The upstream is returning valid Cache-Control headers, which I've verified are correct by visiting the page in Google Chrome 26 and watching in Chrome Dev Tools.

```
localhost: ~ $ curl -s -o /dev/null --dump-header /dev/stdout  http://localhost/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 21:29:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

But when I query the page via the Squid reverse proxy, I always get a cache miss.

```
localhost: ~ $ curl -s -o /dev/null --dump-header /dev/stdout  http://localhost:3128/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 21:29:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/html
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.2.9)
Connection: keep-alive

localhost: ~ $ curl -s -o /dev/null --dump-header /dev/stdout  http://localhost:3128/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 21:29:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15
Cache-Control: max-age=60, public
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/html
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.2.9)
Connection: keep-alive
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: The cache-control header sets max-age to 60, which is the same as squid's default `minimum_expiry_time` - try tweaking this value in squid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, crap, I figured it out.

Squid ignores cache headers less than OR EQUAL TO one minute. So max-age=60 is ignored, but max-age=61 works like a charm.

```
<?php
Header('Cache-Control: max-age=61');

?><html>hi</html>
```

Comment: Or you can tweak `maximum_expiry_time` in squid - which is recommended for this type of environment. :-)

Comment: `minimum_expiry_time`, yes. (You got it right in the comment to the question.)